# SASS - Parent dependent variable re-use?

Tags: sass

I have a SASS based site that has two subsites. They both use exactly the same HTML and CSS layout, but they change some simple brand background colours.

In my SCSS files I have a lot of the following:

```
body.subsite-one {
  #sidebar-second #wrapper p {
    background-color: $primary-color-one;
  }
} 

body.subsite-two {
  #sidebar-second #wrapper p {
    background-color: $primary-color-two;
  }
} 

#sidebar-second {
    padding: 10px;

  #wrapper  {
    border: 1px solid #000;

    p {
      font-size: 17px;
      /* etc... */
    }

  }

}
```

Rather than declare the custom colours outside of the rest of the nesting, which quickly gets unweildy and messy, I'd like to do something like:

```
#sidebar-second {
    padding: 10px;

  #wrapper  {
    border: 1px solid #000;

    p {
      font-size: 17px;
      background-color: $primary-color-($subsite);
    }

  }

}
```

My question therefore: Is there anyway I can set a variable, like $subsite above, that is changed by **parent** classes/id chains?

(**NB**: I can only have the subsite class set on the body, it's not available on any other tag.)

Comment: But where would you set that `$subsite` variable, i.e. how would you make sure that it has a different value on each sub-site? You appear to only have one SCSS file.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I don't mind where I set it - I can have multiple SCSS files (I'm already using a _mixin.css file) - but I'd like to keep the code to a minimum. D.R.Y!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just use the [parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_):

```
#sidebar-second {
  padding: 10px;
  #wrapper  {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    p {
      font-size: 17px;
      .subsite-one & { background-color: $primary-color-1; }
      .subsite-two & { background-color: $primary-color-2; }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a longer list of sub-sites, you could automate that:

```
$subsites      : one  two     three   four   five;
$primary-colors: red  orange  yellow  green  blue;

#sidebar-second {
  padding: 10px;
  #wrapper  {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    p {
      font-size: 17px;
      @each $site in $subsites {
        $index: index($subsites,$site);
        .subsite-#{$site} & { background-color: nth($primary-colors,$index); }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice looking solution, but from what I can tell, relies on the site class being available on the paragraph. It's not, it's only on the body (I'll make this clearer in the OP).

Comment: Nope, this will work with the site class on the body. That's what the `&` is for. It let's you add selectors to the front of the stack.

Comment: In fact, even without the @each, that should make my code a lot more concise. Thanks, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would work, but consider trying:

First, have a "_common.scss" with the common rules:

```
#sidebar-second {
    padding: 10px;

  #wrapper  {
    border: 1px solid #000;

    p {
      font-size: 17px;
      background-color: $primary-color;
    }

  }

}
```

Then, crate a SCSS file for sub-site 1, and let it import that common file, but first set the `$primary-color` variable:

```
$primary-color: red;
@import "common";

// rules specific to sub-site 1 go here
```

Do the same for sub-site 2:

```
$primary-color: blue;
@import "common";

// rules specific to sub-site 2 go here
```

I'm doing a similar thing on my site; check out its source code here:
https://github.com/simevidas/ecmazing-site/tree/master/sass

Answer (score -1):

It occurred to me that the following variation of Eric's answer should (also) work:

```
$subsites: subsite-one subsite-two;

#sidebar-second {
  .case-study-aside-block  {
    .views-field-title .field-content span {
      @each $var in $subsites {
        background-color: $primary-color+$var;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't easily test this at the moment, due to a [possible bug](http://drupal.org/node/1840356) in my Drupal powered SASS compiler.

(Alternatively, if i can't concatenate the vars, I could step through the second list as he suggested.)